# What's the proper way to convert to unicode?

Tags: python, unicode

Say you have a string

```
s = "C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\beeline.txt"
```

that you want to move to Unicode if it's not.

```
return s if PY3 or type(s) is unicode else unicode(s, "unicode_escape")
```

If there's a chance that the string will have a \U (ie, a user directory) and you'll probably get Unicode decode errors.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 3-4: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Is there anything wrong with just forcing it like so:

```
return s if PY3 or type(s) is unicode else unicode(s.encode('string-escape'), "unicode_escape")
```

Or is explicitly checking for the existence of \U ok as it's the only corner case?

I want the code to be work for both python 2 & 3.

Comment: You might want to use raw literals here: `s = r"C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\beeline.txt"`

Comment: Be sure to make up your mind clearly on what to do with input like `s = r"C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\pr\U000000eat-\U000000e0-porter"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine with English, but when faced with an actual unicode example, the forcable translation might not use the same encoding as it would by default, leaving you with unpleasent errors.

I wrapped your given code in a function called assert_unicode (replaced the is with isinstance) and ran a test on text in hebrew (which is simply saying 'hello'), check it out:

```
In [1]: def assert_unicode(s):
            return s if isinstance(s, unicode) else unicode(s, 'unicode_escape')    

In [2]: assert_unicode(u'שלום')
Out[2]: u'\u05e9\u05dc\u05d5\u05dd'

In [3]: assert_unicode('שלום')
Out[3]: u'\xd7\xa9\xd7\x9c\xd7\x95\xd7\x9d'
```

You see? both return a unicode object, but there's still a lot of difference. And if you try printing or working with the second example, it would probably fail (a simple print for example failed for me, and I'm using console2 which is very unicode-friendly).

The solution to this? **use utf-8**. It is a standard these days, and if you make sure everything will be treated as utf-8 as well, it should work like a charm for any given language:

```
In [4]: def assert_unicode(s):
            return s if isinstance(s, unicode) else unicode(s, 'utf-8')    

In [5]: assert_unicode(u'שלום')
Out[5]: u'\u05e9\u05dc\u05d5\u05dd'

In [6]: assert_unicode('שלום')
Out[6]: u'\u05e9\u05dc\u05d5\u05dd'
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I guess 'unicode_escape' in the python docs threw my off.  I'm wondering what it'd be used for now.

Answer (score 0):

The below routine is similar in spirit to the answer by @yuvi, but it goes through multiple encodings (configurable) and returns the encoding used.  It also handles errors (passing by only converting things that are basestring) more gracefully.

```
#unicode practice, this routine forces stringish objects to unicode
#preferring utf-8 but works through other encodings on error
#return values are the encoded string and the encoding used
def to_unicode_or_bust_multile_encodings(obj, encoding=['utf-8','latin-1','Windows-1252']):
  'noencoding'
  successfullyEncoded = False
  for elem in encoding:
    if isinstance(obj, basestring):
      if not isinstance(obj, unicode):
        try:
          obj = unicode(obj, elem)
          successfullyEncoded = True
          #if we succeed then exit early
          break
        except:
          #encoding did not work, try the next one
          pass

  if successfullyEncoded:
    return obj, elem
  else:
    return obj,'no_encoding_found'
```

Answer (score 0):

> What's the proper way to convert to unicode?

Here it is:

```
unicode_string = bytes_object.decode(character_encoding)
```

Now the question becomes: I have a sequence of bytes, what character encoding should I use to convert them into a Unicode string?

The answer depends on where the bytes come from.

In your case, the bytestring is specified using a Python literal for bytestrings (Python 2) therefore the encoding is the character encoding of your Python source file. If there is no character encoding declaration at the top of the file (a comment that looks like: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`) then the default source encoding is `'ascii'` on Python 2 (`'utf-8'` -- Python 3). So the answer in your case is:

```
if isinstance(s, str) and not PY3:
   return s.decode('ascii')
```

Or you could use Unicode literals directly (Python 2 and Python 3.3+):

```
unicode_string = u"C:\\Users\\Eric\\Desktop\\beeline.txt"
```

Comment: Maybe I should have asked, "What's the proper way to convert to unicode if you don't know what the source will be?".  (the example string is from a config file so I can't use the literals directly and I'd like this to run regardless of OS or Python version)

Comment: @Alex: who writes the config file? What prevents you from saving it using a known character encoding (e.g., `'utf-8'`)? It doesn't matter what the OS or Python version are.

Comment: any random user could edit the config file using whatever editor they wish.

Comment: @Alex: Instruct your users to save as `'utf-8'` using whatever editor they wish. If you can't trust them to do it then what prevents them from putting any binary garbage into the file? If a file contains text; you should know its character encoding to be able to interpret it correctly. [There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)